# How to process prettyfaces 'query-param' in backing bean?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I have a list of users(dataTable with a link on `userId` that points to `/user/view/{userId}`). On clicking this `userId` link, the browser is redirected to the 'view' page as expected.

I have a page that accepts the url pattern `http://localhost:8080/user/view/1` for first user and `http://localhost:8080/user/view/2` for the second etc, but I don't know how to use the `userId` value once this page loads.

How can I achieve this with [PrettyFaces URLRewriteFilter](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/)? How can I load data using the value of `#{bean.userId}` (1,2, etc) from the backing bean once PrettyFaces has injected it when the page is accessed. Can anybody explain?

```
<url-mapping id="view">
<pattern value="/user/view/#{bean.userId}/" />
<view-id value="/userview.jsf" />
</url-mapping>
```

I am using JSF2+Primefaces.3.0.M3+Prettyfaces-jsf2.3.3.2 with GAE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a page-load action, specified by the `<action>` element in your URL-mapping configuration. First, you will need a method in your bean, like this:

```
@Named("bean")
@RequestScoped
public class LoginBean {

public String loadLoggedUser() {
    if ( userId != null ) {
        this.user = user.findById(userId);
        return null;
    }
    return "failure";
}
}
```

Second, you will need to add the `<action>` to your URL-mapping:

```
<url-mapping id="view">
     <pattern value="/user/view/#{bean.userId}/" />
     <view-id value="/userview.jsf" />
     <action>#{bean.loadLoggedUser}</action>
</url-mapping>
```

Here we have defined a page-action to be executed on a bean, `#{bean.loadLoggedUser}`, when a URL matching our pattern is requested. For example: `/user/view/2`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<url-mapping id="login">
        <pattern> /user/view/1 </pattern>
        <view-id> /legacy/user/login.jsp </view-id> <!-- Non JSF View Id -->
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="register">
        <pattern>/user/view/1 </pattern>
        <view-id>/faces/user/register.jsf</view-id> <!-- JSF View Id -->
    </url-mapping>
<url-mapping id="login1">
        <pattern> /user/view/2 </pattern>
        <view-id> /legacy/user/login2.jsp </view-id> <!-- Non JSF View Id -->
    </url-mapping>
    <url-mapping id="register2">
        <pattern>/user/view/2 </pattern>
        <view-id>/faces/user/register2.jsf</view-id> <!-- JSF View Id -->
    </url-mapping>
```

refer http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/

Comment: But I have a lot of users . So I need something like `<pattern> /user/view/#{bean.userId} </pattern>`. And I was asking how can I process this `#{bean.userId}` in the backing bean?

Comment: To clarify, I think what you mean is "I want to load data using the value of `#{bean.userId}` when the page is accessed."